# Translate coordinates between different CRS

Tags: coordinate-system

There are two Coordinate Reference System, say they are wgs84 and crs2(a local crs).

A certain location can be translated from wgs84 to crs2 by official algorithm, and the algorithm is irreversible(Because the algorithm is confidential).

Now we have a lot of locations in crs2, and we want to translate them to wgs84.

We tried to use the grid to make this.

For example, we can generate millions of points in wgs84 which have a certain distance with each other, then they will make up a gird.

Then we translate these points to crs2 one by one by the algorithm. After that, for a given point in crs2, we first find the gird it reside in , and then calculate a approximate location in wgs84.

Like this:

[image]

And the precise depend on the distance of the gird, the small the better.

I am just not sure if there is any models or best practices out of box for building the grid and make the reverse calculation as fast as possible?

Comment: might help us to know what cs1 & cs2 are

Comment: They are all local crs, seriously they can not be called as crs.

Comment: "There are two Coordinate Reference System" versus "seriously they can not be called as crs." How is the algorithm irreversible? Are you talking about a *resampling* problem?

Comment: I just though that you can take the crs2 as the china mars coordinate system, and crs1 as normal wgs84.

Comment: I am not sure what is this kind of calculation called, so I add a picture to make it clear about what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is basically the way that datum shifts with ntv2 grids work (in both directions with the same grid file), but they are developed to exchange between degree coordinates.

Comment: Luckily  the crs1 and crs2 are both degree coordinate system. And I want to get a good solution to save the grid,points and their relationships which can make the reverse calculation as fast as possible.

Comment: I am not sure why this post is downvoted. I have tried my best to make me clear enougth

Comment: By what algorithm do you transform coordinates one way? You may be able to invert that algorithm to transform them back the other way.

Comment: The algorithm is confidential

Comment: Is pt1 always (e.g.) to the right of pt2, or is the position scrambled? Does the output grid pattern visually match the input grid pattern, like the image in the question?

Comment: Yes, the relative position of the points are preserved. For the output grid, that's what I am not sure how to build it. This is what I am doing now:http://www.pastebin.ca/2969113, however it seems that the result are not as expected:http://i.stack.imgur.com/6UP1x.png  As shown, the points are not straight. During my calculation I use the algorithm here:http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how is the algorithm irreversible? There should be a clear bijection between points in a CRS translation.

Comment: Because we do not OWN the algorithm.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to calculate using a common basepoint between the two grids?  For a given point in crs2, calculate the distance and bearing to the basepoint, then calculate what point is the same distance and reverse bearing from the basepoint in wgs84?

Comment: "The algorithm is confidential" but you expect us to divine some understanding from your garbled question! You need to address all our comments, carefully, in English, and in the question (not in the comments).

Comment: I have posted that "the algorithm is irreversible" at the first edition of my question.

Comment: If the relative positions are preserved, then you can derive an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) to do forward / inverse mapping of coordinates, which can be solved with a few pairs of points from each coordinate system. A 2D affine transformation matrix has 6 coefficients, so you need a minimum of 6 points to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transform is unknown, you could use one of the commonly used models that would estimate your transform. If the speed is an issue, you should start with the most simple solutions, check the precision of your model based on the RMSE (you seem to have a large number of points, so you can have a good estimate of the RMSE) and then increase the complexity of your model if necessary.

Because you work in geographic coordinate system, selecting a datum transform should be the most usefull. You can find a selection of equation-based algorithm (geocentric and molodensky) an [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Equation_based_methods/003r00000012000000/).

Another solution is to convert the grids as if they were planar coordinate systems. This would work if your area of interest is small. You could then start with an affine transform, and if it is not precise enough you can use first or second order polynomials.

Comment: Does it mean that the brute-force solution I mentioned make no sense? One can always calculate the model(equation)(easy or complex) by limited points? And BTW, I wonder if there is any condition when the gird is necessary? If yes, any common practices to building the gird and calculating?

Comment: My point is that simple models are usually more robust and run faster. The local grid based model would be usefull if you had a complex transform with strong distortions (what you do is called rubber sheeting). In your case, I think that we can assume the crs2 is based on a relatively simple model, except if it is a custom transform based on some attribute (like this map, based on population, where your method would be necessary : http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1217571/A-new-world-The-amazing-map-based-population-shows-Britain-big-player.html )

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you. And in fact, why we use the grid calculation is that the crs2 is complete locally and classified by a third organization, so we do not know if the transformation is Equation based or not. If not, does the modeling solution still work if I choose the parameter as complex as possible? In this case(the wgs84-crs2 is not equation based), it seems that this becomes to a complete mathematics problem: find a polynomials `f` which meets:crs2xy = f(wgs84xy), then solve the `f`?